# Keras: chmod results in not finding keras module

Tags: python, keras, chmod

I'm running code from [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/).

When I run the code using:

```
python mycode.py
```

It runs without issue, producing expected output.

However, when I add a line to the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

and run

```
chmod +x mycode.py
```

and then this:

```
./mycode.py
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mycode.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
ImportError: No module named keras.models
```

My end goal is to modify the code to accept things like --epochs from the command line. How can I do this with Keras?

EDIT:

Here's the code that works (run using python mycode.py). You can [obtain the dataset here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data) (a csv, not huge). The problem comes up when I add the shebang to the top and chmod and run the alternate way.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=2, batch_size=10)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the reason is here: `#!/usr/bin/python`. When you running `python` from console it can use another python interpreter (e.g. you have it installed at `/usr/local/bin/python`). So you need to use the same in your script, the easiest way is to declare it like `#!/usr/bin/env python`